# WP custom comment field only on certain page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I added an additional field to my comment section of my wordpress page with the help of a little plugin, based on a tutorial https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/.

It's only one field I need (ZIP Code).

The plugin works fine, but it adds the custom field on every page. I just want it on one specific page.

I tried to wrap all the plugin code into one function that loads on the specific page:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'load-on-certain-page');

function load-on-certain-page(){
        if ( is_page(23) ) {
        //Complete Plugin Code
    }
}
```

Basically that works, but the check for the empty field isn't working anymore.

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data' );

function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
    if (empty( $_POST['title'] ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Fehler: Bitte geben Sie Ihre Postleitzahl ein.' ) );
    return $commentdata;
}
```

If I exclude the field check from my `load-on-certain-page()` function it checks the field everywhere so thats no solution. I also tried to add an additional condition to the if-statement (`is_page()`), but that does not work, too.

Can you point me into the right direction how to make my plugin functions work only on that certain page? And what "best practise" is to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.

The problem is, that is_page() etc. didn't work for the "preprocess_comment" filter.
But you can check the page ID the comment will be assigned to by using:

```
$post_id = $commentdata['comment_post_ID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can possibly add an if/else statement to only show the field on that specific page...

```
if ( $post->ID === 23 ) {
    // Input for zip code on page 23
} else {
    // No input for zip code
}
```

Comment: Thats what I'm doing. But the part for checking the field doesn't work anymore when I put it into that statement. :/

Comment: I noticed you're using `is_page()` - have you tried it with `$post->ID`?